# Using computer to capture traffic between Android device and AP

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a wi-fi camera that acts as an Access Point. The control over the device is maintained over an Android app. I discovered that this app is communicating with the device with simple http requests. I did that by emulating Android on my computer and then capturing packets with Wireshark. What I would like to do however is to avoid emulating Android since it causes problems.

So this is how I would like this to work:

My smartphone connects to the computer via wifi and then all of its connections are transferred to the wifi camera (something dmz like). Meanwhile I capture all the traffic between smartphone and camera.

I have 2 external wifi cards, one could work as AP for smartphone and the other as client to the camera's AP. But how should I set this up?

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't a security question either. You are trying to set up an ad hoc wifi network. That's a networking question.

Comment: What you want to do is to sniff the wifi to capture the traffic between the camera and the smartphone.

Comment: A far simpler way would be to put all devices on the same network, and set your phone to use the computer either as an HTTP proxy or as the route needed to connect to the camera. Then, you can simply proxy or forward the traffic through the computer and sniff it. The router option may be needed if the app does not respect system proxy settings.

Comment: Something like [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) would be perfect for your scenario.